W11 last files opened by application
In W10, if I click on Start, then right click on an application like Word, a list of the last few files opened with Word appears in a pop up.  I can then select the file I wish to edit and Word opens with that file.
Currently, for something that simple on WXP, W7 and W10, I have to click on Start, open All Apps, hunt for Word (which happens to be buried in the Office menu), and then right click on it to get a list of files.
I can use the recent files list from explorer but the application it opens with isn't necessarily the one I would like to use.  For instance, sometimes I want to open csv files in Notepad++ instead of excel.
Is there an easy way to do this on W11?  When I right click, all I get is `Unpin from Start', 'Pin to taskbar' etc but no list of files.

Recent opened available in taskbar

Expanding on @Mr.Key7's reply.  Other click means right click for right handed mouse settings and left click for left handed mouse settings.
Other click on Word, pin to taskbar
Once the item is on the taskbar, other click on the icon and it will show the list.
